# Re-registering an RStudio Addin

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio

I have written an [RStudio addin](https://rstudio.github.io/rstudioaddins/) (a [Shiny gadget](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/gadgets.html)), which I have been successfully been able to register in RStudio by installing the package from GH. However, when I made some changes, pushed to GH and re-installed the package, RStudio does not appear to register the latest version of the addin. How can I get RStudio to do this? The R package that contains the addin is [here](https://github.com/tchakravarty/TCAddins).

Comment: Did you pin down a root cause for this?  I am currently having the exact same issue, with my package located here: https://github.com/amormachine/RStudioAddIns
A similar package, which appears to be working, though with few discernable differences, is located here:
https://github.com/BAAQMD/copydat